# Magento 1.9 layout getChildHtml not loading

Tags: layout

For some reason my childhtml is not loaded inside a template file.

I updated my `local.xml` file with:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs_product.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related.top" as="related_top" template="catalog/product/list/related_top.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="seotitle" as="seotitle" template="catalog/product/seotitle.phtml"/>
        <!--Add Tabs-->
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>description</alias>
                <title>Description</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Inside `catalog/product/view/description.phtml` I load:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seotitle'); ?>
```

But for some reason that file is not loaded. It works perfect for the default `catalog/product/view.phtml` template.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`seotitle` is a child of `product.info` (which is rendered with *`view.phtml`*). I think you could use another reference to the tab and declare the `seotitle` there.

Edit: Something like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs_product.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related.top" as="related_top" template="catalog/product/list/related_top.phtml"/>
        <!--Add Tabs-->
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>description</alias>
                <title>Description</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="description">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="seotitle" as="seotitle" template="catalog/product/seotitle.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain this with an example of what we need?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but sadly it does still not add the childhtml.